isosceles trapezoid building : search mathematical relation between matrix scaling factor transformation and angle
by using the following script, it is possible to compute coordinates of isoceles trapezoid:
    import numpy as np
    
    # given parameters
    long_base = 4
    height = 1
    scale_factor = 0.404229

    # long_base coordinates 
    half_lb = long_base/2
    A =np.array([[-half_lb , 0. , 0.], [half_lb , 0.  ,0.]])
    
    # format matrix to apply transformation
    one = np.ones((A.shape[0],1))
    A= np.append(A, one, axis=1)
    
    # transformatipn matrix 
    
    matrix = np.array([[scale_factor, 0, 0, 0], 
                       [0, 1, 0, 0], 
                       [0, 0, 1, 0], 
                       [0, 0, height, 1]])
    # new coordinates
    B = A @ matrix
    
    A = np.concatenate((A,B), axis=0) 

the following parameters are provided as data:

long base size
height
scaling factor


Resulting angle is function of these parameters. As an example if

long base size = 4
height = 1
scaling factor =   0.404229

then the angle = 40

I would like to know the mathematical relationship that relates these parameters to the resulting angle. I would like to be able to provide as data a factor which makes it possible to obtain a given angle. Does anyone know this mathematical link?

Scaling factor is not well defined

@MadPhysicist Meaning that there is no way to find an expression relating those parameters ?

No, there is clearly some simple arithmetic and trigonometry that will give you the result. Three problem is that I can think of a number of ways of interpreting the scaling factor number, all of which are plausible and will yield different results.

Assuming that "scaling factor" means what the base scales by to get the top, then:
top = scaling_factor * long_base
total length cut off at top = long_base - top = (1-scaling_factor) * base
half total length cut off at top = (long_base - top)/2 = (1-scaling_factor) * long_base / 2
tan(angle)=height/(half total length cut off at top)

Hence
angle = math.atan( height / (0.5 * long_base * (1 - scaling_factor)) )

Make sure that you multiply by 180/pi if you want it in degrees.

thank you it works !
angle = np.radians(60)
scaling_factor = 1 - (height / (np.tan(angle) * long_base * 0.5 ))

adaptating your equation, I'm now able to find the scaling_factor to obtain a specific angle !
